# When does FolderRelativeId change?

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10

When does FolderRelativeId change? The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.istorageitemproperties.folderrelativeid) is scant.

- When a file's content changed?
- When a file's name is changed?
- When a file is moved?
- When a folder's name is changed?
- When a folder is moved?
- When some sort of OS level re-index takes place? (not sure if such an event exits)

It definitely changes. Don't store a FolderRelativeId in the hopes of using it later.